# SQLITE and PYQT5 stopping to respond on sql execution

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I was building a todo app and used the sql-lite python database for it. I added the clear command and all was going well until I found out when I cleared the database and then tried to view it, my pyqt application just stopped responding.
The database code:

```
def db(self):
    title = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
    desc = self.textEdit_2.toPlainText()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS task
                           (title text, desc text)
                           """)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO task VALUES(?,?)", (title, desc))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

the code to view the database [within qt application]

```
def showdb(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    str = ''
    str2 = ''
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(50)
    tableindex = 0
    amount = len(cur.execute('SELECT * FROM task').fetchall())
    if amount > 0:
        for x in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM task'):
            str = ''.join(x[0])
            str2 = ''.join(x[1])
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tableindex, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tableindex, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str2))
            tableindex += 1
    else:
        pass
```

the code to clear the database [it stops to respond after i click it]

```
 def delete(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('DROP TABLE task')
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your delete function, after dropping the database you are not creating it again. This line of code should fix the error.

```py
def delete(self):
  conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute('DROP TABLE task')
  cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS task
               (title text, desc text);
             """)
  conn.commit()
```